# Redux-thunk actions

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-thunk

I have actions/index.js file with action creators, and I am using redux-thunk as middleware. This is the code:

```
export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/current_user');
    dispatch({type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data});
};

export const handleToken = (token) => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/stripe/', token);

    dispatch({type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data});
};

export const submitSurvey = (values, history) => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/Surveys', values);

    history.push('/Surveys');
    dispatch({type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data});
};

export const scrollMovement = (scrollValue) => dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: SCROLL_MOVE, payload: scrollValue})
};

export const selectConfig = (id) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({type: "SELECT_CONFIG", payload: id})
};
```

And I have a question. Should I write action creators, which do not send a request to external API (for example, scrollMovement and selectConfig), at the same style, as I write hadleToken, submitSurvey, and fetchUser action creators?

I hope that you understand my question. If not, add comments, I will explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an a synchronous flow of data, you just need to return an object as normal you do, because, under the hood, thunk middleware intercepts actions of the type function before the dispatch is generated.

So for `scrollMovement` and `selectConfig` you don't have to return a function because these follow an a synchronous flow of data

```
export const scrollMovement = scrollValue => {
    return {type: SCROLL_MOVE, payload: scrollValue}
};

export const selectConfig = id => {
  return {type: "SELECT_CONFIG", payload: id}
};
```

Comment: `dispatch` is undefined

Comment: but `dispatch` in this case will be undefined, yeah

Comment: Yes sorry you are right I edited my post, you only need to return an object that is your action if you are following a an  synchronous flow.